# Typesafe higher order function mimicing the interface of any passed in function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a higher order function. The basic idea is that high is passed a function fn, and it returns a function that takes the exact same parameters and gives the same return type.

It's an exercise in trying to understand the language better. I have something that works but erases the type from the input parameters. Please see the types Test1 vs Test2 below:

```
export function high<R>(fn: (...args: any[]) => R) {
  return (...args: any[]) => {
    const moddedArgs = args.map((el) =>
      typeof el === "string" ? el + "OMG" : el
    );

    return fn(...moddedArgs);
  };
}

const test1 = (nr1: number, str1?: string) => (str1 ?? "Wow").repeat(nr1);

test1(3, "yo");
// returns yoyoyo

test1(3);
// returns WowWowWow

const test2 = high(test1);

test2(3, "yo");
// returns yoOMGyoOMGyoOMG

type Test1 = typeof test1;
// type Test1 = (nr1: number, str1?: string) => string

type Test2 = typeof test2;
// type Test2 = (...args: any[]) => string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwBaYDmeAPAEoB8AFAigFxxUB0LAhlIQM4OsoCeAbQC6ASjgBeCnDJiA3gCg4cKMBhIouZmw7c4vQaIlSFSpWhyd4AWwgATW8FsBBHRL06mV1mCpVgAGzFJRVMlGD4wYAgEOACJcXE4ACJLKEwUQiS4AH5Y-zgAamSAeQBZAHEshgCQpREAbnla5VV1XFotTzsHZx0GkIBfRoGm8xRLOBhgSwBGNyoUKBmGFCQrACNgKAAaOFSZ7IZU9MIgqSp9nNykgHUIAHckkSYVSNYYBaX++SnZqgBmXZJPgQJ6NAD04Jaag0nDgIIRECavxgMwB-Uh0LacLu91xuNGFngKIATG4CMQqCiZt9SQCgSCwfJMSoYeN4RAyuUQVyeRVkRFgHAACrTVFucKRaKTMUzCFQyVC0WzeaLZZwVYbLa7faHPYwNIZM76w2EAWREVismJRXS0nyyaCy2Wa2MFhMdhcHj8YTG44ZIA)

I tried having a P type argument for the parameters, which I sort of got working But it didn't handle optional parameters well.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to guess generics for the `fn` function parameters and return types separately, we can have a single generic type `F` for the whole function, and then extract its constituent types with [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) TypeScript built-in utility types:

```
export function high<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: F) {
  return (...args: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> => {
    const moddedArgs = args.map((el) =>
      typeof el === "string" ? el + "OMG" : el
    );

    return fn(...moddedArgs);
  };
}

const test2 = high(test1);
//    ^? (nr1: number, str1?: string | undefined) => string
```

---

We can even go a little further, in case it might make sense in your case: by asserting the modified function as having *exactly* the same type as the original function (type `F` above), we get its associated JSDoc as well!

```
function high2<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: F) {
  return high(fn) as F // If we assert the returned function type as exactly F, we get its associated JSDoc as well!
}

const test22 = high2(test1);
//    ^? (nr1: number, str1?: string) => string
// In the IDE, we should have any JSDoc associated to test1, popup as well on test22, since it is said to be exactly the same type.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwBaYDmeAPAGJygzAoAmAznABQB0bAhlIfQFxzsoAngG0AugEo4AXgB8-ITKYIUfMpIDeAKDhwowGEii5WHLrzgAFTuwC2+4FHrkZ4vgCV9hlABVBYYM7Sclo6Omg49PA2ELS0wLQAgmbS-GYsNuxgTEzAADaSstqhOjB+wBAIlLnSUlJwAESRUJgohPVwAPxVcADUDQDyALIA4u18eUU64gDcmpO6nkaIKCbpMXGJZjNFAL6zO3MA9ABUx3AAyhB2cABS5wAiEGhwx4ea4SiRcNSRAIwpTBQUF+fBQSBsACMHAAaOBNX4dPhNFqEApyJjwzpdeoAdQgAHd6uIWHp-OwYIDgdtDodigA9DpzH4wX5MADMsPqgggRNmNIWBiMjG5IogTOAf3Z1NpekFnzgePxisVcw+X2ZACYUgRiExmb9pfTGZpNezOdzeZp+bKvMKIENhtyHU6RkyynBvBKWSlSv4Kt8vb8+bTfcAPYGAUCQXAwZCYXCYMDEQnmq00SmUW7-OHIlq6qH-Zrg993Z7cwC2CxONw+AIRBIghnWnNkOgsDh8EQ8BryJQQNQ6IxVtXzHWxOm64plKoNEUbUsdXglChJOxGBR+QBJSr4sNr+gOeAwPBh+coeKIVAYbC4UP8RigdgYXKCOBkWG7uCEfRwTAwRj7k8mDkhedyPM8a5wLuuS5AAhJoBzvBER5ehqeadsQGp6oGhqhAymhAA)

Comment: Thanks! You and Tobias sort of wrote the same thing at the same time, except that you had a little bit more meat on your answer and also the great tidbit about the JSDoc.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the whole type of `fn` in a generic type. To type `...args`, we can use `Parameters<Fn>`.

```
export function high<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: Fn) {
  return (...args: Parameters<Fn>) => {
    const moddedArgs = args.map((el) =>
      typeof el === "string" ? el + "OMG" : el
    );

    return fn(...moddedArgs);
  };
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwBaYDmeAPAGK6gzAoAmAznABQB0bAhlIfQFxzsoAngG0AugEo4AXgB8-ITKYIUfCpIDeAKDhwowGEii5WHLrzgAFTuwC2+4FHrkUMybLhadOtDnrwbELS0wLQAgmbS-GYsNuxgTEzAADZuMtpeOjCCYMAQCHDJ0lJScABEflCYKISlcAD8BUlwANRlAPIAsgDitXzJ6TriANyaA7r6hrjKJjGBwWFmw+kAviPLoz4ofnDUfgCMkUwoUHt8KEg2AEYOADRwFXt1fBVVhKnMD-UNpQDqEADupXELD0OXYMCOJyWml2MD2TAAzHdSoIIECRgB6DHjAxGRiogkQUaw+EIpZYnGTRh-f40mkbXzwWEAJkiBGITBJ0JZiORqPRmgpelxWzgqM6XXF3SlXWJ2WAcAAKsB9pEsjk8jsVXDMdj1QrlaqSpDTnBzldbvcYCcnlbKtV3i9qnKckrtaySvrNSzdTt5W6-B7mGwWJxuHwBCIJNI5E7CEA)